# Julia Micro-Benchmark Statistic Recommendations

Tags: julia, performance-testing

What do people in the Julia community consider to be the most valid statistic for micro-benchmark performance test comparisons?

For example, the `BenchmarkTools` macro `@benchmark` reports the:

- minimum time
- median time
- mean time
- maximum time

Over the years I have seen arguments for the minimum time, but my background in statistics makes me cautious of that recommendation.  I could be wrong, of course, since I am coming from a different problem domain.

I did find some interesting recommendations [here](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00764454/document).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is what I have found so far:

A credible organization for benchmarking for software performance seems to be [SPEC](https://www.spec.org/):

> The Standard Performance Evaluation Corporation (SPEC) is a non-profit corporation formed to establish, maintain and endorse standardized benchmarks and tools to evaluate performance and energy efficiency for the newest generation of computing systems. SPEC develops benchmark suites and also reviews and publishes submitted results from our member organizations and other benchmark licensees.

[SPEC Members](https://www.spec.org/consortium/) are clearly influential in computing.  Here is the current list, not counting Associates, etc.

> Acer Inc. * Action S.A. * Advanced Micro Devices * Amazon Web Services, Inc. * Apple Inc. * ARM * ASUSTek Computer Inc. * AuriStor Inc. * Avere Systems * Bull SAS * Cavium Inc. * Cisco Systems, Inc. * Dell, Inc. * Digital Ocean * Epsylon Sp. z o.o. Sp. Komandytowa * Format Sp. z o.o. * Fujitsu * Gartner, Inc. * GIGABYTE Technology Co., Ltd. * Google Inc. * Guizhou Huaxintong Semiconductor Technology Co. Ltd * Hitachi Data Systems * Hitachi Ltd. * HP Inc. * Hewlett Packard Enterprise * Huawei Technologies Co. Ltd. * IBM * Inspur Corporation * Intel * iXsystems Inc. * Lenovo * Microsoft * NEC Corporation * NetApp * New H3C Technologies Co., Ltd. * NVIDIA * Oracle * Principled Technologies * Pure Storage * Qualcomm Technologies Inc. * Quanta Computer Inc. * Red Hat * Samsung * SAP AG * Sugon * Super Micro Computer, Inc. * SUSE * Taobao (China) Software Co. Ltd. * Unisys * Veritas Technologies * VIA Technologies * VMware * WekaIO *

They provide "SPEC CPU2000 Run and Reporting Rules" [here](http://www.spec.org/cpu2000/docs/old/runrules-V1.2.html).

Here is the relevant part to this discussion (bold emphasis added):

> Purpose
>   This document specifies how the benchmarks in the CPU2000 suites are to be run for measuring and publicly reporting performance results, to ensure that results generated with the suites are meaningful, comparable to other generated results, and reproducible (with documentation covering factors pertinent to reproducing the results).
>
> Per the SPEC license agreement, all results publicly disclosed must adhere to the SPEC Run and Reporting Rules, or be clearly marked as estimates.
>
> The following basics are expected:
>
> - Adherence to the SPEC general run rule philosophy, including
>
>   - general availability of all components within 3 months of publication.
>   - providing a suitable environment for C/C++/Fortran programs.
> - Use of the SPEC tools for all published results, including:
>
>   - compilation of the benchmark with the SPEC tools.
>   - **requiring the median of at least three runs of each benchmark to help promote stability and reproducibility**.

Using the median is part of their procedure, as seen in the bold text above.

Comment: From a statistical perspective I would probably use all of those and I would calculate a range and standard deviations to determine variability in run times. I would use SDs if you ran your benchmark multiple times. But there is probably a better suggestion than this.

Comment: @Mike Have you run come across the "use minimum time" recommendation?  Thanks for comment.

Comment: I have come across if before - Here is a good article that discusses the pros and cons of min vs average - http://blog.kevmod.com/2016/06/benchmarking-minimum-vs-average/

Comment: @Mike Thanks for link!  I will take a careful look.

Comment: In general, I hope that the minimum time is what I want.  If the timed function is actually doing the work I want to measure, then it must be closest to the minimum time.  If the actual execution time was longer, it would mean that during the minimum time the function didn't do its work.  Of course, there are practical considerations that need to be considered for comparison. E.g., is some function related overhead more often incurred with one function rather than another, etc.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks for comment.  Have you looked at [these](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00764454/document) recommendations?  I am just learning of them, but they look a lot like what I am familiar with in environmental statistics.

Comment: Yeah, and I think on a "program scale" measurement their recommendations make sense.  First one needs to decide what is being measured.  For a very small function, the executed machine code generated by the compiler and the performance of the processor/memory/bus/etc./etc. is most easily compared.  For example, if two functionally equivalent functions are compiled/assembled to 10 and 30 machine instructions, respectively, where each machine instruction takes the same number of clock/bus/memory cycles, I think I probably want the 10 instruction version.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes, context is crucial in statistics.  Good point.